# Is there a way to check if a generator is in use anywhere globally? Such that an active generator will bail if no one is using it

Tags: python, scope, reference, generator

Is there a way to check if a generator is in use anywhere globally?  Such that an active generator will bail no one is using it.

This is mostly academic but I can think of numerous situations where it would be good to detect this.  So you understand, here is an example:

```
def accord():
  _accord = None
  _inuse = lambda: someutilmodule.scopes_using(_accord) > 1
  def gen():
    uid = 0
    while _inuse():
      uid += 1
      yield uid
    else:
      print("I'm done, although you obviously forgot about me.")
  _accord = gen()
  return _accord

a = accord()
a.__next__()
a.__next__()
a.__next__()
a = None

"""
<<< 1
<<< 2
<<< 3
<<< I'm done, although you obviously forgot about me.
"""
```

The triple quote is the text I would expect to see if someutilmodule.scopes_using reported the number of uses of the variable.  By uses I mean how many copies or references exist.

Note the that the generator has an infinite loop which is generally bad practice but in cases like a unique id generator and other not widely or complexly used, it is often useful and won't create huge overhead.  Obviously another way would simply be to expose a function or method that would see the flag where that the loop was using as it's condition.  But again it's good to know ways to do various ways to do things.

Comment: It should automatically be garbage collected once no references to it remain. Is there something beyond that that you need?

Comment: I'm aware that even if the utility function existed tis code wouldn't work because execution after the yield only starts when the next yield is issued but let's pretend it would for the sake of focusing on the actual question.  To do this properly there would need to be a watcher that would routinely check the use and then tell it to stop.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That sounds likely.  Are you sure?  I was unsure because i don't know the internal function of yields, I thought they might keep the generator persistent. But I suppose the developers would have thought of that and handled it.

Comment: If you're interested, I linked to the relevant source code that handles this specific task, as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, when you do

```
a = accord()
```

A reference counter behind the scenes keeps track of the fact that a variable is referencing that generator object. This keeps it in memory because there's a chance it may be needed in the future.

Once you do this however:

```
a = None
```

The reference to the generator is lost, and the reference counter associated with it is decremented. Once it reaches 0 (which it would, because you only had one reference to it), the system knows that nothing can ever refer to that object again, which frees the data associated with that object up for garbage collection.

This is all handled behind the scenes. There's no need for you to intervene.

The best way to see what's going on, for better or worse, is to examine the relevant [source code for CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9684fac5a158be9806304a676e619857520a4dc/Include/object.h#L432). Ultimately, `_Py_DECREF` is called when references are lost. You can see a little further down, after interpreting some convoluted logic, that once the reference is 0, `_Py_Dealloc(op);` is called on `PyObject *op`. I can't for the life of me find the actual call to `free` though that I'm sure ultimately results from `_Py_Dealloc`. It seems to be somewhere in the `Py_TRASHCAN_END` macro, but good lord. That's one of the longest rabbit holes I've ever gone down where I have nothing to show for it.